VBA Save View or Distribution
I have set-up the Watches and Immediate windows some ways I like:

I have set-up the toolbars, watches, Immediate, and other things a visible in the screenshot above.
I was wondering if there is a way I can save this "appearance Settings" so I don't have to go through it everytime I open VBA.
Thank you.

I think you will need to set up the two code editing windows each time, but everything else stays the same each time I open my VBA IDE (watches don't persist, although window does)... I Do have macros recorded and saved to PERSONAL.XLSB, so maybe that is what makes it persist for me?
